# Web API - Accept incoming POST, pass off operation and close connection ASAP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an interaction with another server which makes POST calls to my web app.  The problem I have is that the server making the calls tends to lock records which my app would go back to update.

So I need to accept the post, pass it off to another thread/process in the background and get the connection closed as soon as possible.

I've tried things like:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(myTestModel passIn)
{

if (ModelState.IsValid) {
   logger.debut ("conn open);
    var tasks = new []
   {
      _mymethod.PassOutOperation(passIn)
   }
   logger.debug ("conn closed");
   return Ok("OK");
   }
 return BadRequest("Error in model");
}
```

I can tell by the amount of time the inbound requests take that the connections aren't being closed down as quickly as it could be.  In testing they are just 3 consecutive posts to my web app.

Looking at my logs I would have expected my entries for connection open and closed to be at the top of the log.  However the closed connections are at the bottom, after the operations that I was trying to pass out have completed.

Has anyone got any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side note I've also tried using 'new Thread(()...' in place of 'new[]' in my example code.  This does help the connections open and close quickly, but its behaving as though the new thread is killed off as it only partially executes the code that is handed to it.  No errors to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone interested I solved the problem.

I'm now using:

```
var tasks = new thread(() =>
{
  _mymethod.PassOutOperation(passIn);
});
tasks.start();
```

The reason the code was stopping was because I was originally passing HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName in my other method.  Which was out of scope when I setup the new thread.  I've since changed now and declare a variable outside of the code block which create the new thread, and pass in via the methods constructor e.g.

_myMethod.PassOutOperation(passIn, userHostName);

Hope that helps someone in the future!